# webpack serve: liveReload flag doesn't work

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-cli

Packages:

```
"node": "14.14.0,
"npm": "6.14.8",
"webpack": "^5.10.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
```

I was trying to use example from https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverlivereload without effects...

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [
        {
          from: /.*/,
          to: '/index.html',
        },
      ],
    },
    contentBase: resolve('public'),
    compress: true,
    port: 8080,
    hot: false,
    liveReload: false,
  },
  ...
}
```

If I run `webpack serve --config webpack.config.js` I get

```
[WDS] Live Reloading enabled.                               index.js:52
```

in browser console and app still reload page after change in any watched file.

I want disable liveReload flag to turn off live reload for webpack server.